# $\int_0^\infty J_0(ax)e^{-px} dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+p^2}}$ without using Laplace transform tables

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I have been tasked to show that $$\int_0^\infty J_0(ax)e^{-px} dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a^2+p^2}}$$ using the series expansion for $J_0(x)$ and **not** the Laplace transform tables.

where $$J_n(x)=\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{s}}{s!(s+n)!}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2s+n}$$

After substituting $J_0(ax)$ I'm really struggling to deal with the infinite sum inside the integral and would really grateful if someone could show me how you go about this.

$$\int_0^\infty\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{s}}{s!s!}\left(\frac{ax}{2}\right)^{2s}e^{-px}dx$$

Comment: Since integration is a linear operator, move the infinite sum outside the integral along with all the terms that don't have an $x $.  Then perhaps integration by parts to evaluate the integral.

Comment: It may be more convenient to use the integral $$J_0(x)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{\cos (x u) du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

The Laplace transform of $x^n$ is $\frac{n!}{p^{n+1}}$. So you can apply this to the series representation you have 
$$
J_0(a x)=\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{s}}{s!^2}\left(\frac{a x}{2}\right)^{2s} \to  \sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{s}a^{2s}}{s!^22^{2s}}\frac{(2s)!}{p^{2s+1}}= \mathcal{L}_{x\to p}[J_0(ax)]
$$
then
$$
\mathcal{L}_{x\to p}[J_0(ax)] = \frac{1}{p}\left[\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(2s)!}{s!^24^{s}}X^s\right] = \frac{1}{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-X}}
$$
where $X=-\frac{a^2}{p^2}$, then 
$$
\mathcal{L}_{x\to p}[J_0(ax)] = \frac{1}{p}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{a^2}{p^2}}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2+a^2}}
$$
of course this relies on the knowledge of
$$
\sum_{s=0}^\infty\frac{(2s)!}{s!^24^{s}}x^s = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}}
$$
which some will say is basic and others will not, but it's not from a Laplace transform table.